# How to add a edge/testing package to Alpine Linux?

Tags: docker, .net-core, azure-webjobs, alpine-linux

I have an Azure Linux WebApp using docker-compose to run three containers: Asp.Net Core 3.1 WebApp, Nginx as reverse proxy and an Asp.Net Core WebJob (SKD 3) to gerenate PDF reports. The WebApp is at https://pdf.ricardogaefke.com.

The problem is: the PDF generated has a QrCode with a link to check on it online and I was facing a problem while running the WebJob ("`libgdiplus` was not found) and I tried to install this [libgdiplus package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86/libgdiplus). This problem is related to `System.Drawing` Namespace.

The problem is that package is in a edge/testing version and it cannot be installed using `apk add` command. How can I install this package?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It was possible to install the edge/testing package using the `repository` option, like this:

```
RUN apk add libgdiplus --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/
```

Now my WebJob is generating PDF files (the problem was about generating the QrCode as a Bitmap) perfectly. You can check on it at https://pdf.ricardogaefke.com. The Dockerfile with `libgdiplus` install is [here](https://github.com/RicardoGaefke/ricardogaefke-pdf/blob/master/Dockerfile.webjob.pdf.cloud).